# use selected branch on workflow_dispatch in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

[image]

Hi everyone, I am building Github actions workflow to use **master** and **develop** branches.
I know that i can check out branch by reusing actions like below, but how do i actually pass variable form the manual workflow_dispatch dropdown?

```
   uses: actions/checkout@v2
   with:
     ref: develop
```

Since workflows can be created only in default branch, the only workaround is to create trigger workflow that is reusing core workflow and passing branch as parameter.

**UPDATE**
Here is the code for master (production) branch

```
name: Trigger ECR deploy


on:
  release:
      types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  deploy-terraform:
    uses: <reusable-workflow-path>
    with:
      AWS_REGION: "ap-south-1"                  
      ECR_REPOSITORY: "repo-name-here"
      BRANCH: "master"
    secrets:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

This is another file for staging env

```
name: Trigger ECR deploy


on:
  release:
      types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  deploy-terraform:
    uses: <reusable-workflow-url>
    with:
      AWS_REGION: "ap-south-1"                  
      ECR_REPOSITORY: "repo-name-here"
      BRANCH: "develop"
      ENVIRONMENT: "staging"
    secrets:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Both these files are in master branch at the moment. I recreated staging file in develop branch (i kept the name of the file the same). However, when i go to trigger workflow i still get this error as seen on screenshot. The parameters that I pass to reusable workflow is like a workaround.

Comment: `Since workflows can be created only in default branch`. That statement isn't true. A workflow needs to be on the default branch to appear on the _Actions_ tab on the Github repository, but you can have the sane workflow in more than one branch. In your case, you could have this workflow on the **master** and the **develop** if you wish, each one with a different implementation. Did you try it?

Comment: Hi @GuiFalourd, I didnt know that. I just tried it, but i still see that error when i try switching branch on workflow dispatch dropdown. I have 2 files with same names and same titles ( name: **). I assumed that 2 files in different branches can be linked if file names are same, but it doesnt look like it.

Comment: Could you give more details of what you try editing the question? 

Comment: Thank you @GuiFalourd, I have updated the question with my workflow files code snippets.

Comment: Ok. Everything should work as expected if the workflow **filename** was the same (let's say, `.github/workflows/deploy.yml`) on the **default** branch and the **develop** branch. However, how are you calling the reusable workflow there? Are you using the branch name as well to specify which version of the reusable workflow needs to be used (with `@main` or `@develop`) ?

Comment: No, i call reusable workflows in my public repository (separate from calling repo) and it is in @main branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved a while ago. As Sir GuiFalourd mentioned in the comments, files indeed should be in both branches to be accessible. I cannot say exactly why that didn't work, but I realized that to allow workflows in staging and prod branches to function properly and don't cause overwrite on merge (unless we ignore it), I needed to create a universal workflow that allows conditional run.

Answer (score 3):

Can you confirm that your workflow files are in `.github/workflows/<workflow.yml>`?

Also, to answer your original question about being presented with variable inputs in the GUI, you will need to define the variables within the `on.workflow_dispactch` section (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch):

```
name: Trigger ECR deploy


on:
  release:
      types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      AWS_REGION:
        description: 'AWS Region to deploy in'
        required: true
        default: 'ap-south-1'
        type: choice
        options:
        - ap-south-1
        - ap-south-2
        - ....
      ECR_REPO:
        description: 'ECR repository'
        required: true
        type: string
      BRANCH:
        description: 'Branch to use'
        required: true
        default: 'master'
        type: choice
        options:
        - master
        - develop
  
jobs:
  deploy-terraform:
    uses: <reusable-workflow-path>
    with:
      AWS_REGION: ${{ inputs.AWS_REGION }}                  
      ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ inputs.ECR_REPO }}
      BRANCH: ${{ inputs.BRANCH }}
    secrets:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to check.

[official docs - workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch)

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
        type: choice
        options:
        - info
        - warning
        - debug
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
        required: false
        type: boolean
      environment:
        description: 'Environment to run tests against'
        type: environment
        required: true

jobs:
  log-the-inputs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "Log level: $LEVEL"
          echo "Tags: $TAGS"
          echo "Environment: $ENVIRONMENT"
        env:
          LEVEL: ${{ inputs.logLevel }}
          TAGS: ${{ inputs.tags }}
          ENVIRONMENT: ${{ inputs.environment }}
```